# How to pass data from guard of a child component to parent component?

Tags: angular, router-outlet, angular-router-guards

I have a parent component that has a bun of tabs with links. Each tab has a link that will navigate to the child component. The parent tab has a header data such as client name, dob, gender, ...

The parent component `.HTML` looks like the following:

```
 <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        <mat-chip-list aria-label="Title" class="table_title">
          <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Client Detail</mat-chip>
          <mat-chip color="accent" *ngIf="clientName">Client Name: {{ clientName }}</mat-chip>
          <mat-chip color="accent" *ngIf="clientAlias">DOB: {{ clientDOB }}</mat-chip>
          <mat-chip color="accent" *ngIf="clientAlias">Gender: {{ clientGender }}</mat-chip>

        </mat-chip-list>
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
          [routerLink]="['./demographics']"
          (click)="activeLink = 'demographics'"
          [active]="activeLink == 'demographics'">
          <mat-icon class="tab-icon">contact_page</mat-icon>
          Identifying Information
        </a>
        <a mat-tab-link
          [routerLink]="['./contacts']"
          (click)="activeLink = 'contacts'"
          [active]="activeLink == 'contacts'">
          <mat-icon class="tab-icon">contacts</mat-icon>
          Contacts
        </a>
      </nav>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

The router outlet will render the appropriate child component based on the tab name.

Parent component `.ts` looks like the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Calling the resolver and updating the activeLink
    this.activeLink = this.route.snapshot.data.tab;

    // Set the header data
    this.route.data.subscribe(resolvedData => {
      if (resolvedData.headerData !== null) {
        this.clientName = resolvedData.headerData.fullName;
        this.clientDOB = resolvedData.headerData.dob;
        this.clientGender = resolvedData.headerData.gender;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/clients']);
      }
    });
  }
```

Navigating (rendering) the child component (**demographics**) will let the user edit the client info such as name, gender, dob.

The save of the client demographics page (component) is done using a guard (Deactivate) which means the user can't navigate to the contact page or other page (tab) unless data is valid.

My deactivate guard looks like the following:

```
if (model.dirty && model.valid) {
      // call the saving service
      this.clientService.UpdateClientIdentInfo(personId, model.getRawValue()).subscribe(updatedHeaderData => {
        // TODO: PASS updatedHeaderData TO THE PARENT COMPOENET
        this.snackBar.open('Data has been saved successfully!', '', {
          duration: 2000,
          horizontalPosition: 'center',
          verticalPosition: 'bottom',
          panelClass: ['snack-success']
        });
        return true;
      }, error => {
        return false;
      })
    }
```

The response of this API call **updatedHeaderData** will have the new data that I want to pass to the parent component so all of its header data gets updated.

Here is my app routing model

```
{
    path: 'clients/:id',
    component: ClientDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      tab: ClientDetailsResolver,
      headerData: ClientDetailHeaderDataResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'demographics',
        component: ClientIdentInfoComponent,
        resolve: { client: ClientIdentInfoResolver },
        canDeactivate: [ ClientIdentInfoGuard ]
      },
      {
        path: 'contacts',
        component: ClientContactComponent,
        resolve: { PersonContacts: ClientContactsResolver},
        canDeactivate: [ ClientContactsGuard ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'demographics',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Service here. Something like this.

***HeaderDataService***

```
private pHeaderData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

get headerData(): Observable<any> | any {
    return this.pHeaderData.asObservable();
}

set headerData(data: any) {
    this.pHeaderData.next(data);
}
```

***ParentComponent***

```
const subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

constructor(private headerDataService: HeaderDataService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription.add(
        this.headerDataService.headerData.subscribe( data => {
            console.log('delivery from ChildComponent arrived: ', data);
        })
    );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

***ChildComponent***

```
constructor(private headerDataService: HeaderDataService) { }

if (model.dirty && model.valid) {
  // call the saving service
  this.clientService.UpdateClientIdentInfo(personId, model.getRawValue()).subscribe(updatedHeaderData => {

    // inform the parent
    this.headerDataService.headerData = updatedHeaderData;

    this.snackBar.open('Data has been saved successfully!', '', {
      duration: 2000,
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      verticalPosition: 'bottom',
      panelClass: ['snack-success']
    });
    return true;
  }, error => {
    return false;
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, Lynx.
Thank you for your answer.. I don't think this will work.. if you looked at the app routing, each route uses a resolver which its component gets the resolved data in the OnInit cycle.. The parent component would be already loaded so you can't use the OnInit cycle if this makes sense.

Comment: I thought about the BehaviorSubject and I bumped into how to update the elements of the component after the onInit has finished

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but it sounds like you are not familiar with the concept of a subscription to an Observable. The magic about it is, that it doesn't matter when you subscribe. Because you only tell the Observable that you want, from now on, to get informed about each change to the object the Observable carries. It is clear that your parent component is running long before the child component comes alive. But once again. The parent just told the Observable to get informed about changes and gets the new object handed over inside the subscribe-method.

Comment: A BehaviorSubject is possible as well. But you usually only need it when you have a use case where you have to access the value inside the subject without waiting for the event triggered by `.next()`. Please note, that you only subscribe inside `onInit()`. The subscription will stay as long as the component is alive. So each time some method puts a new value into the Subject and thus triggers `.next()` your parent component gets an update. This has nothing to do with `ngOnInit()` in general. You could move this subscription into the constructor as well. It would work.

Comment: Give the code a try. You'll see that it will work.

Comment: Thank you Lynx for your response. I guess your answer makes sense when you said that it does not matter when you subscribe.. basically as long as the subscription is there, it does not matter the time.. I am gonna give it a try, however, the aren't we gonna get an error because the your set and get accessor does not have the same type?

Comment: Yup, I am getting this error -> error TS2380: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Lynx.. Please update your answer to include Observable<any> | any for the getter